# How to Check If Some Futures in a Collection Have Failed

Tags: scala

I used traverse to execute a collection of futures like this:

```scala
val result: Future[List[Either[Error, Int]]] = Future.traverse(urls)(foo(_))
```

I end up with a `Future[List[Either[Error, Int]]]`. How can I check that one of these futures resulted in an Error?

I tried to do this but I think it is wrong because I am reading that you cannot substitute variables for futures?

```scala
    val check: Future[Boolean] = result.map{
      fut => fut.exists(c => c.isLeft)
    }

    check.map{
      b => b match {
        case true => // do something
        case false => // do something
      }
    }
```

Comment: You could Await the result and then check if it failed. Or you can map over it, similar like you've done. You could also flatMap it or do onComplete and check result.

Comment: so what I did is not wrong? I thought once the future is executed and I map over it then I cannot use it again. What I want to do is that in the true case I want to return the List of Ints

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the `result` to a list of errors like this:

```
val errors: Future[List[Error]] = result.map(_.collect{ case Left(err) => err })
```

It is then possible to use `Await.result` to extract these error values, but that is nearly always a bad idea because it blocks the current thread.

It is better to ask "What do I want to do once the `Future` is complete but returns errors?". Then implement that behaviour in a `map` or `foreach` on the `errors` `Future`.

Comment: What I want to do is to return an Error if the one of the futures fails but if none of them fail them I want to return the list of ints

Comment: @Mojo What is returning this error and who is going to process it? The point is that once you create a `Future` your code is asynchronous and trying to make it synchronous again is going to cause all sorts of problems,

Comment: I see what you mean. I will try to work with your solutions. My balls are getting kicked in ferociously today :((